# Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio (3.1.3) with build tools 28.

The layout does not get rendered in the design tab when I'm using coordinator layout. Many have pointed out that to get around this problem is to add the following lines in the `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

However adding the lines produces the following error: `Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout'`.

Is there away to get around this issue?

Comment: first add style that inherint from parent `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  ///code...
</style>`

Answer (score 14):

Try (API 28)->

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!--<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>-->
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I don't fkn care why, but it works! We 're already accustomed with android sh*ts!

Comment: Silly google developers. Stop moving things around, but think more when you create them. Grrrrrrrrrrh

Answer (score 5):

This works in my version of studio (3.1.3):

Change this 2 lines in your gradle app file (build.gradle)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

and resync.

Delete line

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

if you still have it in your styles.xml file.

Comment: Works as well as in 3.2 stable!

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I Hope  this will work for you.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

add above line in app gradle file and instead of 27.1.1 use your library version(i.e 28.x.x)

Comment: I already have that implementation in the dependencies block of my `build.gradle`:
`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'`

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1' use alpha1 instead of alpha3 in your app gradle.

Comment: please remove that style. use alpha1 as a dependency.
when you use coordinator layout it will render the ui in design tab.
I have tasted it works.

Comment: Apparently changing the dependency from `alpha3` to `alpha1` fixed the error `Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme`. Thanks!

Comment: please remove coordinatorLayoutStyle from both- styles.xml as well as from layout.

Comment: this is working for me @style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout