# I am not able to preview my app in the design tab of xml file in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am not able to preview my app as I am building it in .xml file in the both the design and text tab. The app runs fine on the emulator. I have tried changing the theme, changing the API, force refresh layout, cleaning and rebuilding the project and also Invalidate caches/restart. None of them work for me. The android studio version is 3.1.3. Please help.

Following are the screenshots if they provide any help to you.

Here is manifest file
[image]

[Here is the java file-Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg1Kp.jpg)
[image]

[Here is the java file-Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avi4P.jpg)
[image]

[Here is design tab of xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl2YR.jpg)
[image]

[Here is text tab of xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00LHt.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and i add below code to AppTheme in style file:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">  
               .
               .
    <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item> //add this line
         </style>
```

If above code give an error change support library versions as bellow and delete above code:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1' or  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'    or   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

If problem not solved add above code again  to Apptheme.
You can change compile sdk and target sdk version to 27.
(This is a bug in android studio 3.1.3 !)

Comment: You can also visit this post [Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015934/cannot-resolve-symbol-style-widget-design-coordinatorlayout)